# How to pass parameters to a jinja2 flask function call?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to pass a parameter to a context_processor function.

```
@app.context_processor
    def my_utility_processor():
        def foo(var):
            return var
    return dict(foo=foo)
```

The jinja/html template part looks like that:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="var name={{ i.DeviceName }};this.disabled=true;alert('{{ foo({{ variable }}) }} ')">
Click</button>
```

Is it somehow possible to pass a jinja2 parameter to a jinja function call?

Answer (score 3):

Once you enter a `{{ ... }}` block you are governed by Python's syntax.

```
alert('{{ foo(variable) }} ')"
```

Depending on the output of `foo`, though, this could cause a JavaScript error. You can go one step further and make Jinja format the output for you

```
alert({{ foo(variable)|tojson|safe }})
```

This will take care of things like quoting strings for you.

Comment: not quite what I intend to do. I have to call a function and pass a parameter to that function. The parameter is a jinja parameter {{ ... }}. I guess the only solution/workaround is to make a form with hidden post parameters and @app.route function.

Comment: What is a "Jinja parameter"? If both `foo` and `variable` come from Python, that's how you do it. If, however, `variable` is JavaScript, you can't pass a JavaScript variable directly into a Python function, you need to make a request to the server.

Comment: I am looping in jinja template `{% for i in devices %}` and I want to make a button which calls a python function: `{{ foo({{ i.DeviceName }}) }}`

Comment: Buttons can't call Python functions. The best you can do is trigger a request (which will be mapped to a Python function).

Answer (score 0):

From what I read here: https://sopython.com/canon/103/use-jinja-variable-in-function-call/

"Don’t nest curly braces within a Jinja expression, you’re already *in* the expression"

So for your case, you should simply write:

```
alert('{{ foo(variable) }}')
```

(Note: I didn't try it yet)